# Undefined method order_by for Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am getting the error: "undefined method 'order_by'" but I thought that the order_by method was built in for Sunspot, can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

My Searchable block within my model:

```
searchable do
  text :title, :street_address, :apartment_number, :city, :state, :zip

  float :price
  float :bathrooms
  float :bedrooms
  float :average_overall_rating
end
```

My search controller method:

```
def search
  @search = Apartment.search do |query|
    fulltext params[:search]
    order_by(:average_overall_rating, :asc)
    with_price(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have access to the `order_by` method in the Sunspot search DSL. Do this in your controller instead:

```
def search
  @results = Sunspot.search(YourModel) do
    fulltext(params[:search])
    order_by(:average_overall_rating, :asc)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fulltext` and `order_by` methods must be used in the `search` block of the model. It should be something like:

```
def search
  @models = Model.search do   # Replace 'Model' by your model class
    fulltext params[:search]
    order_by(:average_overall_rating, :asc)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I actually found out the solution by intuition:

All I need to call is query.order_by(:average_overall_rating, :asc)!